# Induced morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let a morphism of $k$-algebras $f:k[y_{1},\cdots,y_{m}]\rightarrow k[x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}]$, defined by $y_{j}\mapsto P(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n})$. Mi question is the following one: the morphism induced in the spectra is $f^{*}:\mathbb{A}^{n}_{k}\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{m}_{k}$, if we considerer a point $(\lambda_{1},\cdots,\lambda_{n})$, which is the image of the point by $f^{*}$? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I presume $y_j$ is mapped to $P_j(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. In that case
$\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}(\la_1,\ldots,\la_n)$ maps to
$(P_1(\la_1,\ldots,\la_n),P_2(\la_1,\ldots,\la_n),\ldots,P_m(\la_1,\ldots,\la_n))
$.